What to add/change in script so after selecting something from menu it returns to menu and not exits
I found this bash script to make a menu and it is wonderful except I would like it to stay in the script, return back to the menu after something has been selected unless the last option exit has been selected. Also when something is selected the output has to stay shown until a key has been pressed which returns back to the menu.
Can anyone help me out, I would very much appreciate help.
Here is the script
#!/bin/bash

HEIGHT=15
WIDTH=40
CHOICE_HEIGHT=4
BACKTITLE="SOULMASK SERVER MENU"
TITLE="Title here"
MENU="Choose one of the following options:"


OPTIONS=(1 "login info"
         2 "Soulmask status"
         3 "Option 3"
         4 "exit")




CHOICE=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$BACKTITLE" \
                --title "$TITLE" \
                --menu "$MENU" \
                $HEIGHT $WIDTH $CHOICE_HEIGHT \
                "${OPTIONS[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

clear
case $CHOICE in
        1)
            w ; uptime
            ;;

        2)
            /usr/bin/systemctl status soulmask
            ;;

        3)
            who
            ;;

        4)
            exit
            ;;

esac


I tried putting breaks in, but it gave me syntax errors.

After OPTIONS=... just add while :; do and then at the end of the script after esac (case backwards) add done. (that just wraps all commands after the OPTIONS array in a continual while loop - : is a no-op) Also, rewrite to remove ALLCAPS variable names. ALLCAPS are generally reserved for bash system and environment variables.

Always paste all your scripts into ShellCheck to help you catch and fix errors. It is a wonderful tool that will save you a lot of grief.

Simplistically, you could just use the built-in select loop.
$: ./tst
1) cat ./tst
2) date
3) ls -l ./tst
4) exit
#? 1
#! /usr/bin/bash
select option in "cat $0" date "ls -l $0" exit; do $option; done
#? 2
Mon Jul  1 09:03:02 CDT 2024
#? 3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 P2759474 1049089 82 Jul  1 09:02 ./tst
#? 4
$:

I don't really like select and have virtually never used it, but it's in the toolbox.
Maybe something like this -
menu="
  Choose one of the following options:

         1 this script file's contents
         2 current date and time
         3 a directory listing of this script
         4 exit the script

"
clear
while read -p "$menu" option
do clear
   echo
   case $option in
   1) cat $0 ;;
   2) date ;;
   3) ls -lF $0 ;;
   4) exit ;;
   *) echo " *** Invalid option. ***" ;;
   esac
   read -p "

     (<RETURN> to continue)

   "
   clear
done

Personally, I'd rather just do it this way:
#! /usr/bin/bash
use="
  $0 {c|d|l}

  c cat this script
  d date and time
  l ls this script

"
case $1 in
c) cat $0 ;;
d) date ;;
l) ls -lF $0 ;;
*) echo " *** Invalid option. *** $use" >&2; exit 1;;
esac

but that's not what you asked for.
Hope this helps.

Thanks, but personally I like how the menu looks which Ive originally found. But it is nice to see how you script these menu's and I am learning from this which is even more important to me.
